# Exponential type of $\sin z$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions, inequality, exponential-function

An entire function $f$ is of exponential type if $\,\lvert\, f(z)\rvert\le C\mathrm{e}^{\tau\lvert z\rvert},\,$ for all sufficiently large values of $\lvert z\rvert$.

The exponential type of $f$ is the infimum of all $\tau$ satisfying the above inequality.

I am trying to determine the exponential type of $\sin z$, so far without any luck - hope you guys can help me!

Comment: have you tried eulers formula for sine? ( in terms of complex exponentials)

Comment: Yes, I have tried working with it - I feel like that is the way to go. So far I have $|\sin(iy)| \leq \frac{1}{2}e^y$ for $y>0$

Comment: ... and also for $y<0$, I have $|\sin(iy)| \leq \frac{1}{2}e^{|z|}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First observe that ($z=x+iy$)
$$
\lvert\sin z\rvert\le\frac{1}{2}\lvert\mathrm{e}^{iz}\rvert+\frac{1}{2}\lvert\mathrm{e}^{-iz}\rvert=\frac{1}{2}\big(\mathrm{e}^{y}+\mathrm{e}^{-y}\big)\le \frac{1}{2}\big(\mathrm{e}^{\lvert z\rvert}+\mathrm{e}^{\lvert z\rvert}\big)=\mathrm{e}^{\lvert z\rvert}.
$$
Hence $\tau\le 1$.

Then, for $z=iy$, with $y>0$, we have
$$
\lvert\sin z\rvert\ge\frac{1}{2}\big(\mathrm{e}^y-\mathrm{e}^{-y}\big)\ge \frac{1}{4}\mathrm{e}^y=\frac{1}{4}\mathrm{e}^{\lvert z\rvert}.
$$
The second inequality holds for $\mathrm{e}^{2y}\ge 2$ or $y\ge\frac{\log 2}{2}$.

Hence $\tau\ge 1$.

Comment: Thanks, I think that will do!

Comment: Wait, how do you get the first equality when $z=iy$? I seem to get $\sin(iy) = \frac{1}{2}(e^y-e^{-y})$

Comment: @MadsFriis See my updated answer.